# Make a visible div hide and an invisible one appear while clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what I have so far, one div is visible by default and the other is hidden. However when I click the button they both appear/disappear together. What am I doing wrong?

```
var hideprofiles = function () {
var mydiv = document.getElementById('newpost');
if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
    mydiv.style.display = 'none';
else
    mydiv.style.display = 'block'
```

}

}

```
var showprofiles = function () {
var mydiv2 = document.getElementById('NewProfile');
if (mydiv2.style.display === 'block' || mydiv2.style.display === '')
    mydiv2.style.display = 'none';
else
    mydiv2.style.display = 'block'
```

}

```
<div id="newpost2">asdf</div>
    <input type="submit" value="btn" onclick="hideprofiles(); showprofiles();  "></input>

<div id="newpost">
    <table class="full_width_table" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="currentprofile">Current Profile:</td>
            <td id="selectcurrentprofile">
                <select>
                    <option value="train_manager">Train Manager</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td id="company">Company:</td>

            <td id="selectcompany">
                <select>
                    <option value="XC">XC</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <a data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-position-to="window" data-mini="false"
                    data-include-close-btn="false" href="dialogs/new_UserProfile.html" id="createbutton">Create</a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
        </div>

<div id="NewProfile" class="hide_element">

       <table class="full_width_table">
```

Edited to include some more details like was asked

Comment: where is your `NewProfile` element? where is `hideprofiles()` ? show more code.

Comment: where are `NewProfile` and `newpost` in your HTML?

Comment: Updated with the html elements

Comment: Updated by removing unrelevant jQuery tag...

Comment: Sorry for not phrasing the question the best fellas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="btn" onclick="toggle()">
```

Js:

```
var toggled = false,
    div1 = document.getElementById("newpost"),
    div2 = document.getElementById("NewProfile"),
    toggle = function( ) {
        if( toggled ) {
           div1.style.display = "block";
           div2.style.display = "none";
        } else {
           div1.style.display = "none";
           div2.style.display = "block";
        }
        toggled = !toggled;
    };
```

this should be the easiest and most performant way. [example](http://jsbin.com/papava/1/edit)

Edit:
The Javascript must be included after defining `newpost` and `Newprofile`:
It would not make a difference when `div1` and `div2` where defined inside `toggle`. 
But when defined outside (which is more performant since its only executed once) it is executed on page load.

Pages load from top to bottom, so when reaching the lines with `div1` and `div2` the parser will search for `newpost` and `NewProfile`, which are not defined at that very moment, when the js-file is loaded before these elements are. 
This means he can not find them and `div1` and `div2` are `undefined` which is why `toggle` won't work.

Furthurmore loading js-files at the bottom of your page will ensure less visual delay for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I see the jsscript and how it works on there, but in the context of my code the button just doesn't trigger anything. My js is in a different class, could that make a difference? It's exactly like you had!

Comment: use my html for the button and copy the js to your js file and it should work. be sure, that the js file is included at the bottom of the html page, so `newpost` and `NewProfile` can be found.

Comment: I've got it at the top, moved it to the bottom and it worked! Does it make a difference where your JS links go? I didn't think it did! Could you explain to me how it makes a difference? :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with jquery toggle() easily

```
<div id="newpost1">fdgf</div>
<div id="newpost2">asdf</div>
<button>Toggle</button>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#newpost2").hide();
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("#newpost1").toggle();
    $("#newpost2").toggle();
   });
  });
</script>
```

This is working code. :)

Answer (score 0):

i would count on their style but set their behavior.

```
function showProfiles(){
document.getElementById('newpost').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('NewProfile').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideProfiles(){
document.getElementById('newpost').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('NewProfile').style.display = 'none';
}
```

this way you guarantee that only one of the divs is displayed at a time.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the help! This kind of worked, it gets rid of one and then shows the other. But if I press the button again then it doesn't change back, what needs to be changed to make that happen? :-)

Answer (score 0):

following code hides/shows two divs alternating:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function btnOnclick() {
                var div;
                for(var i = 0, ids = ["div1", "div2"], ceiling = 2; i < ceiling; i++) {
                    div = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
                    if(div.style.visibility == "hidden")
                        div.style.visibility = "visible";
                    else
                        div.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="btnOnclick()"/>
        <div id="div1" style="background-color: #FF0000; height: 50px; width: 50px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
        <div id="div2" style="background-color: #00FF00; height: 50px; width: 50px; visibility: visible;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var showprofiles = function () {
var mydiv2 = document.getElementById('NewProfile');
if ($(mydiv2).is(":visible"))
    $(mydiv2).hide();
else
    $(mydiv2).show();
}
```

Comment: this does essentially the same thing the OP did (way less performant), so this won't solve the problem

Comment: And please don't mix Jquery and Javascript.